# How to target first column of next row with specific class in table

Tags: jquery, calendar

I've been trying to crack this jQuery mystery with various solutions to no success. I have a calendar that uses the classes `.available` and `.unavailable` and I am trying to create half days. It works if the classes do not start on the first day of the week or end on the last day of the week as per the screenshot below:

[Calendar view on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeHmy.png)

You can see on April it works fine but on May the start day starts on the first day of that week so it does not work. The jQuery I am using to achieve this effect is this:

```
$(".datetimepicker table td.available").next("td.unavailable").addClass("start-day");
$(".datetimepicker table td.available").prev("td.unavailable").addClass("end-day");
```

The problem is because in the table the next `.unavailable` block is in the next `<tr>` but I am not sure how this can be checked so the code block looks like this:

```
<tr>
...
<td class="available cur-month">21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="unavailable cur-month">22</td>
...
</tr>
```

So my above jQuery code does not recognise the class because it is not directly next to it. How can I find out if the next element after `.available` is `.unavailable` if it's separated by a row?

EDIT:

In the end I ended up scrapping this idea and looped through each td and comparing the start and end dates to an array and adding the relevant class. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.closest()` to select the parent `<tr>` and use `.next/prev()` to select the next/prev `<tr>` and use `.find()`

```
$(".datetimepicker table td.available").closest('tr').next('tr').find("td.unavailable").addClass("start-day");
$(".datetimepicker table td.available").closest('tr').prev('tr').find("td.unavailable").addClass("end-day");
```

Comment: I've tried many similar suggestions to this. It gave me [this effect](http://imgur.com/dazxVMm)